# MongoDB SDK Failover not working

Tags: java, mongodb, high-availability, mongodb-java, failover

I have set up a replica set using three machines (192.168.122.21, 192.168.122.147 and 192.168.122.148) and I am interacting with the MongoDB Cluster using the Java SDK:

```
ArrayList<ServerAddress> addrs = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
addrs.add(new ServerAddress("192.168.122.21", 27017));
addrs.add(new ServerAddress("192.168.122.147", 27017));
addrs.add(new ServerAddress("192.168.122.148", 27017));
this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(addrs);
this.db = this.mongoClient.getDB(this.db_name);
this.collection = this.db.getCollection(this.collection_name);
```

After the connection is established I do multiple inserts of a simple test document:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.inserts; i++) {
        try {
           this.collection.insert(new BasicDBObject(String.valueOf(i), "test"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error on inserting element: " + i);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When simulating a node crash of the master server (power-off), the MongoDB cluster does a successful failover:

```
       19:08:03.907+0100 [rsHealthPoll] replSet info 192.168.122.21:27017 is down (or slow to respond): 
       19:08:03.907+0100 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member 192.168.122.21:27017 is now in state DOWN
       19:08:04.153+0100 [rsMgr] replSet info electSelf 1
       19:08:04.154+0100 [rsMgr] replSet couldn't elect self, only received -9999 votes
       19:08:05.648+0100 [conn15] replSet info voting yea for 192.168.122.148:27017 (2)
       19:08:10.681+0100 [rsMgr] replSet not trying to elect self as responded yea to someone else recently
       19:08:10.910+0100 [rsHealthPoll] replset info 192.168.122.21:27017 heartbeat failed, retrying
       19:08:16.394+0100 [rsMgr] replSet not trying to elect self as responded yea to someone else recently
       19:08:22.876+.
       19:08:22.912+0100 [rsHealthPoll] replset info 192.168.122.21:27017 heartbeat failed, retrying
       19:08:23.623+0100 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to 192.168.122.148:27017
       19:08:23.917+0100 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member 192.168.122.148:27017 is now in state PRIMARY
```

This is also recognized by the MongoDB Driver on the Client Side:

```
       Dec 01, 2014 7:08:16 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
       WARNING: Server seen down: /192.168.122.21:27017 - java.io.IOException - message: Read timed out
       WARNING: Server seen down: /192.168.122.21:27017 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [/192.168.122.21:27017]  bc:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
       Dec 01, 2014 7:08:36 PM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector setMasterAddress
       WARNING: Primary switching from /192.168.122.21:27017 to /192.168.122.148:27017
```

But it still keeps trying to connect to the old node (forever):

```
       Dec 01, 2014 7:08:50 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
       WARNING: Server seen down: /192.168.122.21:27017 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [/192.168.122.21:27017] bc:java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
       .....
       Dec 01, 2014 7:10:43 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
       WARNING: Server seen down: /192.168.122.21:27017 - java.io.IOException -message: couldn't connect to [/192.168.122.21:27017] bc:java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

The Document count on the Database stays the same from the moment the primary fails and a secondary becomes primary. Here is the Output from the same node during the process:

> "rs0":SECONDARY> db.test_collection.find().count() 12260161
>
> "rs0":PRIMARY> db.test_collection.find().count() 12260161

**Update:**
Using WriteConcern Unacknowledged it works as designed. Insert Operations are also performed on the new master and all operations during the election process get lost.

With WriteConcern Acknowleged it seems that the Operation is waiting infinitely for an ACK from the crashed master. This could explain why the program continuous after the crashed server boots up again and joins the cluster as a secondary. But in my case I don't want the driver to wait forever, it should raise an error after a certain time.

**Update:**
WriteConcern Acknowledged is also working as expected when killing the mongod process on the primary. In this case the failover only takes ~3 Seconds. During this time no inserts are done, and after the new primary is elected the insert operations continue.

So I only get the problem when simulating a node failure (power off/network down). In this case the operation hangs until the failed node starts up again.

Comment: What version of the MongoDB Java driver are you using?  The log messages indicate an older version.  If you upgrade to 2.12, the log spam will decrease.

Comment: I have used 2.10.1 when I created the post. I also tried it with 2.12.4 and you are right - no Warning messages appear. Thank you for that. But it does not solve my problem that my insert operation seems to hang or waiting for some event when the primary goes down and a new primary is elected. Only after the old primary joins the cluster as a secondary, the programm continues where it stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit specifying a Connection Timeout Value solved the error. See also: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

Does your app still work?  Since that server is still in your seed list, the driver will try to connect to it as far as I know.  Your app should still work so long as any of the other servers in your seed list can gain primary status.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, the app stops working correctly.

For example I have a count of  12260161 Documents in the Database when the primary server fails:
"rs0":SECONDARY> db.test_collection.find().count()
12260161

When the secondary switches to primary, the count stays the same and the app does not perform any insert Operations:

"rs0":PRIMARY> db.test_collection.find().count()
12260161

Comment: I have also appended the output to the question

Comment: Well, a few thoughts:  make sure you're using the latest driver to cover your bases.  but more importantly, fail over can take a bit of time to settle so that for loop is likely to be completely wasted if the election happens midloop.  Once you've detected that your primary is gone, you'll have to try again once the driver has detected the new primary.  It'll be up to you to find out how far in to that loop you made it before the server dropped.  Then you'll have to restart at that point and finish your loop.

Comment: Actually it keeps hanging on the insert Operation from the moment the primary fails until the moment where i bring the failed node back online as a secondary (even when the node is down for minutes). Then it starts continuing within the loop. During the time the node is down the program just hangs and is printing out the Warning "No route to host" . Currently I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 with MongoDB 2.6.5 and on the Client mongo-2.10.1 with Java openjdk-1.7.0.71.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest driver and see what happens.

Comment: I have already done this, I now use 2.12.4 and Java SDK 7u71. Please notice that I have updated the Question. The Error only appears in case the host is not reachable. If I only kill the process the driver works as designed.

Comment: Might be worth filing an issue against the java driver, then.

Comment: I'll first try it out with another driver to see if it is working there or I just have some kind of misconfiguration.